# Крейсер "Аврора" плыл или плыла?

Tags: грамотная-речь, грамматика, общие-вопросы, род, существительные

Возник вопрос из обсуждения на одном форуме, как правильно писать:

1. Крейсер Аврора готов (готова) выйти в море
2. Аврора готов (готова) выйти в море
3. Готов (готова) выйти в море крейсер Аврора.

Если верить [этой статье](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/22-spravka/letters/59-rubric-89), то когда женское имя соединяется с мужской профессией, родом занятий и т.п. как Майор Иванова, Боец Ирина, то действуют правила:

1. Майор Иванова подошлА
2. Майор подошел (при том что она женщина)
3. Подошел майор Иванова
4. Майор, единственная женщина части, подошлА

Вопрос имеют ли эти правила какое-либо отношения для случая крейсера "Аврора", если нет то по какому правилу выбирается тот или иной вариант?

**P.S.** В большинстве, статей в инете находил вариант крейсер "Аврора" поплыл, а не поплыла, но как правильно и почему?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Правильно так.

***Крейсер "Аврора" готов выйти в море.

"Аврора" готова выйти в море.

Готов выйти в море крейсер "Аврора".***

*(Разницы между первым и третьим примером я не вижу, Вы правильно все написали?)*

Согласование идет по родовому имени, если оно есть. Если нет, то в дело, естественно, вступает имя собственное.

> Если верить этой статье, то когда женское имя соединяется с мужской
>   профессией, родом занятий и т.п. как Майор Иванова, Боец Ирина, то
>   действуют правила:...

И это правильно. Но "крейсер" не профессия и "Аврора" не личное имя женщины, а название. Приведенные Вами правила никак не могут быть обобщены на Ваши примеры.

Comment: Ок, спасибо, учту. Да, правильно написал третий случай, в случае с  профессией будет разница.

Comment: Не понял..*Доктор Иванова приняла больного* и *Больного приняла доктор Иванова*?! В чем разница-то?

Comment: Посмотрите ссылку http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/22-spravka/letters/59-rubric-89, там утверждается а) сказуемое в книжно-письменных стилях (особенно в строгой официально-деловой речи) ставится в форме мужского рода: ... 2) если сказуемое предшествует сочетанию «рассматриваемое слово + собственное имя»

Comment: То есть:  Больного приняЛ академик Иванова, а не принялА

Comment: Да, я посмотрел, что там на Грамоте понаписано. Перевариваю. Если навскидку - не согласен. С этим и еще несколькими аналогичными положениями статьи. Сколько живу, всегда слышал только *"диссертант изложила"* и т. п. Посмотрю завтра у Розенталя, если не обленюсь окончательно. При всем уважении к "Грамоте", слепо верить всему, что там понаписано, я бы не рекомендовал.

Answer (score 3):

"Аврора" - приложение по отношению к слову "крейсер". (То же:  газета "Коммерсант", фабрика "Большевик", роман "Молодая гвардия", магазин "Русский лён".)

Как это соотносится с "майором Ивановой", изложено в параграфе [***Некоторые особенности согласования***](http://licey.net/free/4-russkii_yazyk/41-kurs_russkogo_yazyka_russkii_yazyk_i_kultura_obscheniya/stages/783-33_nekotorye_osobennosti_soglasovaniya.html) (речь о подмене грамматического согласования смысловым):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

У Вас:

1. Крейсер "Аврора" готов выйти в море.
2. "Аврора" готова выйти в море.
3. Готов выйти в море крейсер "Аврора".

А вот "подошёл майор Иванова" исключается: [приложением к имени собственному, называющему лицо,](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_(%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0)) является слово "майор".

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

1. Майор Иванова подошла.
2. Майор (женщина) подошла.
3. Подошла майор Иванова.
4. Майор, единственная женщина части, подошла.

Сравните с

*Мария Ивановна, учитель математики, заболела.*

Comment: Офигенная идея, давать скрин неизвестно чьих рассуждений. Для солидности что ли? Но суть-то не в этом. Автор вопроса настаивает на правильности №3. "Подошел майор Иванова", ссылаясь на "Грамоту". Предлагаеть ему  вместо одного ресурса другой, еще более сомнительный без разбора причин разночтений и сути правил - не комильфо, однако.

Comment: Я в общем-то не настаиваю, сам прочитал это правило и удивился. Но вообще хотелось бы знать в каком источнике описано это правило, чтобы быть уверенным что "Грамота" вводит народ в заблуждение.

Comment: У меня "изложено в параграфе *Некоторые особенности согласования"* КЛИКАБЕЛЬНО!

Comment: @Viacheslav Vedenin *Я в общем-то не настаиваю, сам прочитал это правило и удивился. Но вообще хотелось бы знать в каком источнике описано это правило, чтобы быть уверенным что "Грамота" вводит народ в заблуждение.* - не совсем так. Скорее всего просто не очень четкая формулировка, да и все можно обсуждать, догматизм не в моде тут.  Хотя "Грамота" последнее время действительно не блещет. Проблема в другом. "Кликабельный" источник от G.A. - это полный аут. Ни автора, ни названия. Кто писал, кому писал? Зачем писал? С таким же успехом  можно сослаться то, что на сарае написано.